# Plugin to create project tar file and publish it to Nexus in sbt?

Tags: sbt

Is there some kind of sbt plugin that enables publishing result to repository (i.e nexus).
I heard about sbt-native-packager but I need to create tarball (*.tar) and publish it to repository. I prepeare my own task that depends on dist and it repackages result from zip to tar. Next I just try to modify it with description available here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Td389FbdgCY. Unfortunately I get:

```
[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Internal task engine error: nothing running.  This usually indicates a cycle in tasks.
[error]   Calling tasks (internal task engine state):
[error] Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/C:/src/cms/,cms)),Global,Global,Global),projectDependencyArtifacts))) -> Calling
```

What is more additionaly to publishing package in repository I need to automatically create create tag for release in mercurial.

Comment: The native packager actually has publishing settings for `universal:publish`.  You can control where with `publishTo in Universal`.  I'll try to add a full example when I can.

Also `universal:package-zip-tarball` will make your tgz.